# whats the correct syntax for node structure in xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, transformation

i have been trying to get this xsl transformation to run inside my php the xsl runs OK but it doesn't output the values for the for-each section i get all the headers but i don't seem to be able to get it to output anything else here is what curl XML response looks like:

```
<search>
<response status="2">
<errors>
 StartdateEarlierThanToday0Incorrect start date. Start date cannot be earlier than today.0FalseFalse
 </errors>
<number_of_hotels>1 of 1</number_of_hotels>
</response>
<lr_rates>
<hotel>
 <hotel_ref>142680</hotel_ref>
 <hotel_currency>GBP</hotel_currency>
 <hotel_rooms>
  <room>
  <ref>4380316</ref>
 <type>10</type>
 <type_description>Apartment</type_description>
 <sleeps>2</sleeps>
 <rooms_available>0</rooms_available>
 <adults>2</adults>
 <children>0</children>
 <breakfast>false</breakfast>
 <dinner>false</dinner>
 <description>
 The apartment has seperate kitchen area, lounge/dining area, bedroom with double bed and bathroom with bath & shower.
 </description>
 <alternate_description/>
 <rack_rate>140.00</rack_rate>
 <rate>
 <date>01/08/2012</date>
 <formatted_date>01 August 2012</formatted_date>
 <price>Full</price>
 <hotelcurrencyprice>Full</hotelcurrencyprice>
 <numeric_price>Full</numeric_price>
 <numeric_hotelcurrencyprice>Full</numeric_hotelcurrencyprice>
  <requested_currency>GBP</requested_currency>
  </rate>
    <rate>
   <date>02/08/2012</date>
   <formatted_date>02 August 2012</formatted_date>
    <price>Full</price>
    <hotelcurrencyprice>Full</hotelcurrencyprice>
    <numeric_price>Full</numeric_price>
     <numeric_hotelcurrencyprice>Full</numeric_hotelcurrencyprice>
     <requested_currency>GBP</requested_currency>
     </rate>
     <available_online>false</available_online>
    <minimum_nights>1</minimum_nights>
   <bed_type>Double</bed_type>
   <cancellation_policy/>
   <cancellation_days/>
   <cancellation_hours/>
   <room_terms/>
  </room>
 <room>...</room>
 </hotel_rooms>
 </hotel>
 </lr_rates>
 </search>
```

then this is the xsl im tryig to use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<h2>Availability Search:</h2>
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <th align="left">Room Type</th>
    <th align="left">Description</th>
    <th align="left">Availability</th>
    <th align="left">Price</th>
   </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="/">
    <tr>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="type_description" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="description" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="rooms_available" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="rack_rate" /></td>
    </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: ive tried laying out the for-each and value select to various node structure but all i seem to be able to get empty table data

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="type_description" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="description" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="rooms_available" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="rack_rate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This processes only a single node -- the document node `/` and as this has no children named `type_description` or `description` or `rooms_available` or `rack_rate`  -- nothing is output.

Without having time to look more closely, you probably need something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*/lr_rates/hotel/hotel_rooms/room">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="type_description" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="description" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="rooms_available" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="rack_rate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: thanks for your help but after trying this it still inst giving me an output

Comment: @DominicNoble: You need to learn at least the basics of XSLT and XPath -- there may be numerous issues in your code that you'll not have after learning a little bit about XSLT/XPath. You need to do this part, before anybody can help you with deeper and more tricky problems. For example, the XML as provided isn't well-formed -- you need to replace `&` with `&amp;`

Comment: ive tried various xpath expressions i understand the basics xpath expressions and xslt but i dont seem to be able to get this to work cant understand why ive checked encoding thats right im wondering now if maybe my curl script is cutting off the xml header

Comment: @DominicNoble: As I said, start with the XML -- as provided this isn't well-formed XML document and any compliant XML parser raises an error -- which you probably haven't caught.

Comment: unfortunately this is a request generated document i do a curl request that outputs the xml then try and run it through this xsl file but for some reason xsl doesn't output the values apart from the possibility of bad characters i can't see there is a problem with the xml string as it all appears  correctly on my frontend if i port the string there the request all works fine just not the xsl foreach it runs everything up to there

Comment: strange it all works if i save a request as xml and run it in eclipse

Comment: @DominicNoble: THe document you provide in this question is definitely not well-formed -- this prevents the XSLT transformation from even starting.

Comment: sorry i managed to get this fixed it was to do with a issue with trying to use php dom instead of simpleXMLelement to deal with the xml after the curl